# compile on IPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to compile Iphone apps on Iphone? What Cydia apps I need to get? I just want to write the app with notepad and then copy the files to my iphone and compile them.

Comment: what language do you want to use?

Comment: The iPhone uses Objective-C.  He said he wanted to "compile iPhone apps".  So I'm assuming me means Objective-c.

Comment: Isn't that an overkill? Even if the compiler is ported (which I have my doubts..), _why_? There's any particular reason why would you want to do that?

Comment: The iPhone uses C, C++, Objective-C/C++ and since he stated Cydia, he probably can use interpreters as well. Python... :D

Comment: If you want to do iOS development on a PC - just use Adobe AIR and the iOS packager.  If that doesn't work - you really need a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gcc runs on the iPhone with Cydia: http://www.hackint0sh.org/f9/44218.htm

Comment: Yes, but this won't be able to compile a modern Obj-C application.

Comment: It turns out we lack information then. For compiling the latest iOS Objective-C applications, XCode is the way to go. For making his own C or even Python/Ruby codes, that cydia solution works fine enough.

Answer (score 0):

The current compiler is written for i386.  For this to work on an iPhone, you would have to port it to another processor architecture (ARM).  I don't believe any applications currently can support this unless someone wants to rewrite the compiler.